# the scope of react js nested context component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I ran into a case in react js

I have a page have a context wrapping her and inside of this page I have multiple components and some of these components of course has a call for this context as a useContext

and now the case I need inside of one of these components to re-return the entire page again including the context inside of her

now how can the page understand the scope of the use context and call the right context inside of it

I have actually tried it and somehow it did work in the right way ("I mean the nested page was be able to understand the closest scope for her and take the data from the first closest context wrapping her")
but I still don't understand how it that possible !!??

```
const Contextdata = createContext()

const PageContext = ({children , otherProps}) => {

  const id = otherProps?.id || 5

  const handleData = () => {
    if(otherProps){
      return `.... otherProps`
    }else{
      return {} // default otherProps
    }
  }

  /// other handling


  return(
    <Contextdata.provider
    value={{
      id,
      handleData,
      // other handling
    }}
    >
        {children}
    </Contextdata.provider>
  )
}

export const usePageContext = useContext(Contextdata)


/// this page component should be a beginning of the page rendering
const Page = ({otherProps}) => {
    return(
      <PageContext otherProps={otherProps}>
        <PageContent />
      </PageContext>
    )
}

const PageContent = () => {

  return(
    <div>
      <FirstComponent />
      <SecendComponent />
    </div>
  )
}

const FirstComponent = () => {

  const {id , otherProps} = usePageContext()
  //  the question is here how he can detect the scope of the right context
  return(
    <div>{id}</div>
  )
}

const SecendComponent = () => {
  const {id} = usePageContext()
  var otherProps = {id: 6 } // and more other Props
  // as an example
  return(
    <div>
      {id == 5 ? 
        <Page otherProps={otherProps}/>
      : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you have some simplified code for visualising this?

Comment: I tried to add a simple example for the case @Takkie253